# Need to pass a variable in anchor tag

Tags: php, html

I am very new to php, I am having a problem passing data from textbox to a php variable to use it in an *anchor* tag. Below is the code i am using.

```
<form id="searchform" action="fetchvalues.php" method="get">
  <input name="q" id="q" type="text" />
  <input name="searchbutton" id="go" type="submit" value="" />
</form>
```

I want to pass value from searchbutton to anchor tag

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/?q=var" target="_blank">Hello"</a>
```

Comment: Could you update your question to include whether you are looking for a JavaScript (without page refresh) or a PHP (server-side/POST) solution? The extra detail will enable better responses that aren't guesses...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jquery in your project and want to do this on the front end, you can do:

```
<a id="someLink" href="http://www.example.com/?q=var" target="_blank">Hello"</a>

$('#someLink').attr('href', "http://www.example.com/?q=" + $('q').val());
```

With php you'd only be able to set the entered value of `q` on a post. (meaning when someone submits the form)

i.e.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com?q=<?php echo $_POST['q']; ?>" target="_blank">Hello"</a>
```

IF you need to populate the link href without a page refresh, you'll need to use javascript, if you want it to be populated after a form post, you can use php.

Be aware though that the link would need to be on the page set in your forms `action` attribute to populate the link

You should be aware that you take precautions when echoing out form submissions, however the level of questions suggests you've got more to learn before that. (No offense intended)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_REQUEST['searchbutton']))
        {
    ?>
     <a href="http://www.example.com?q=<?php echo $_REQUEST['q']?>" target="_blank">Hello</a>
     <?php 
    }

?>
```

Comment: also can you help me as to how i can get the value from the searchbutton.

Comment: You want to get value of Submit button or input box..??? I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: i need the value of input box

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="searchform" action="fetchvalues.php" method="get">
<input name="q" id="q" type="text" />
<input name="searchbutton" id="go" type="submit" value="" />
</form>
```

On your fetchvalues.php page

```
 <?php
    $val = $_GET['q'];
 ?>
```

then

```
<a href="http://www.example.com?q=<?php echo $val; ?>" target="_blank">Hello</a>
```